# Can't set open files limit for user www-data and process PHP in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, php, command-line-interface, ubuntu-16.04

I am having trouble setting the open files limit for user www-data and process PHP in Ubuntu 16.04.

I have set all the following to 65535:

- /proc/sys/fs/file-max
- /etc/sysctl.conf
- /etc/security/limits.conf (both with asterisk (*) and explicitly with user www-data)
- /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf (and it works for PHP-FPM!)

Still, wenn I grab a php cli process from user www-data, and check via /proc//limits, it shows:

Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
Max open files            4096                 4096                 files

I have searched php.ini which doesn't have a similar setting as php-fpm.conf, so I just copied the one of php-fpm, to no avail as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please add to the question the output of `for php_fpm_pid in $(pgrep php-fpm);do ps -fp $php_fpm_pid;cat /proc/$php_fpm_pid/limits|egrep 'Max open files|^Limit';echo;done` ?

Comment: Hello @MirceaVutcovici, thank your for trying to help. Here's is the output: 

https://pastebin.com/3VSZ08wv 

But to clarify, for PHP-FPM it does work. For PHP cli, it's not working.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Serverfault. I think you should add information on the "why" you need to have more than 4096 open files *per process*, as it may turn out to be unneeded or needing some other solution entirely different than the one you are trying to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change the parameter DefaultLimitNOFILE on files /etc/systemd/user.conf and /etc/systemd/system.conf.

Found on https://www.it-swarm.dev/de/linux/open-file-limit-kann-nicht-ueber-4096-erhoeht-werden-ubuntu/944917651/